# Using EntityManagerInterface in command symfony 6

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I am trying to pass EntityManagerInterface to Command and it looks like the parent constructor only accepts string or null

```
#[AsCommand(
    name: 'app:cleanDB'      
)]
class CleanDBCommand extends Command
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;

        parent::__construct($entityManager);
    }      

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $date = new \DateTime('now');
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
        $shortUrl = $repo->findBy(['createdAt'=>'<'.$date->format('Y-m-d')]);
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);             
        $io->success('You have a new command! Now make it your own! Pass --help to see your options.');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I get the following error

> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::__construct(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type ?string, Container6Yp8i34\EntityManagerGhostE8260f8 given, called in /.../app/src/Command/CleanDBCommand.php on line 28

I have checked the documentation and I cannot find how to use EntityManagerInterface in command. Any ideas would be helpful.

**Figured out the solution:**
I need to pass the command in the constructor
instead of entitymanager to parent constructor like below

```
parent::__construct($entityManager);
```

I need to pass the command as follows

```
parent::__construct('app:cleanDB');
```

Comment: This `parent::__construct($entityManager);` should just be `parent::__construct();` The base command class does not care about the entity manager.  And yest it is fine if a child class's constructor signature differs from that of it's parent.  No need to pass the command name either.  The attribute takes care of it.

Comment: @Cerad I already tried that, in that case I get an error stating  constructor got 0 parameters and requires 1 parameter

Comment: Does your services.yaml has the default configuration with `autowire: true` and     App\: resource: '../src/'

Comment: @PhaniShashank Nah.  You have something else going on.  I have written a gazillion commands almost all of which require dependencies.  The Symfony Command class's constructor does not require any arguments.  If you want to pursue this consider updating your question with a specific example or starting a new question.

Comment: @DylanKAS yes, it has default configuration

Comment: @Cerad yes you are correct, I cannot explain why but I did the following and it works I removed the parameters `parent::__construct();` and cleared the cache and it works just as you suggested. which is strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the parent class here https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/6.3/Command/Command.php#L114. The constructor takes only one argument and that is `$name` which must be strictly string or null. You are trying to pass an EntityManagerInterface object. This will always blow up, no matter what.

Do you need to call the parent constructor with the name anyway? Since you are using the attribute `#[AsCommand]`, I suppose you are defining the name of your command here and the Symfony should get it from the Reflection of the attribute. If you remove your parent constructor argument, it should work just fine. Here you can see that in constructor, if you do not pass anything, it will do the static reflection check:
https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/6.3/Command/Command.php#L71

Also, since you are using attributes, you are on new PHP 8, and I suggest to write types of your variables, also using shorter and modern notation and the whole command should look like this.

```php
#[AsCommand(name: 'app:cleanDB')]
class CleanDBCommand extends Command
{    
    public function __construct(
        private EntityManagerInterface $em,
    ) {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $date = new \DateTime('now');
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
        $shortUrl = $repo->findBy(['createdAt'=>'<'.$date->format('Y-m-d')]);
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);             
        $io->success('You have a new command! Now make it your own! Pass --help to see your options.');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with the way how I wrote the constructor, here you have something to read:
https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#constructor-property-promotion

If you are using PHP 8.1, you can edit the line in the constructor
https://www.php.net/releases/8.1/en.php#readonly_properties

```php
private readonly EntityManagerInterface $em,
```